Question about what amounts to an implied (or implicit) noun in a sentence
Consider this sentence:

I don't doubt that there were a substantial number of people at that event.

This seems awkward to me, and perhaps grammatically wrong -- to me the verb 'were' should be the singular was, because the verb refers to the presence of the people (at the event), not the individual people -- presence is a kind of implied or implicit subject (noun) here -- and since presence is singular, was is correct, and 'were' is incorrect.
Does anyone know? -- or have an opinion about this? -- any feedback appreciated.
At least for style reasons, I prefer was here.
In contrast, the verb were seems fine in this variant:

A substantial number of people were at the event.


Thanks for the reference to the related question -- I will study it.
